# A family of parabola are given: $f(x)=mx^2+(m+2)x+3, m \neq 0.$ Let's observe the set of points in plane $xOy$ through which no parabolas pass

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry

Which of the following are correct?
a.) $S$ is a line segment

b.)$S$ is a line without two points

c.)$S$ contain at least 4 rays

d.)$S$ is made of one parabola and two rays

e.)$S = \emptyset$

The right answer is c.) Why is this ?

I've tried to search for the apexes of the parabolas, but it didn't lead me anywhere... I've also concluded that since m is always different from zero, all the dots with x = 0 are excluded from parabolas and so the set S can't be empty.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think there's a leap in logic to say "all the dots with $x=0$ are excluded from parabolas".  Instead we should note that the only point with $x=0$ on any of these parabolas is $(0,3)$, which happens to be on *all* of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation in the form

$$\left(x^2+x\right)m=y-2x-3$$

and let $S'$ be the complement of $S$ i.e. the set of all $(x,y)$ for which there is a parabola passing through $(x,y)$

$(x,y)\in S' \Longleftrightarrow  \left(x^2+x\right)m=y-2x-3$ has a solution in $m$ with $m\neq  0$

it is easy to see that for $x=0$ only $(0,3)$ is in $S'$ and for $x=-1$ only $(-1,1)$ is in $S'$

for $x\neq 0,-1$, we are able to solve for $m$ but we need to make sure that $m$ is not zero

so the condition here is $y\neq 2x+3$

Therefore $S$ consists of the three lines $x=0, x=-1, y=2x+3$ minus the two points $(0,3), (-1,1)$

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the family helps:

[image]

You see that there are 6 rays where parabolas will not reach. In the limit as $m\to 0$, then the parabolas will approach the line $y=2x+3$, so that will generate two rays (slanted rays). Also, as a function of $x$, notice that when $x=0,-1$, the parameter $m$ does not affect $y$, so the family of parabolas must always pass through $(0,3)$ and $(-1, 1)$. Therefore, the points on the vertical lines above and below these points cannot have a parabola go through them (the 4 vertical rays).